# Is there a way to center datepicker vertically in mat-datepicker?

Tags: css, angular-material

There are two states :

State - 01:

[image]

State - 02:

[image]

In state-01 , "Choose a date" is vertically centered . Like that , I'm trying to center "Choose a date" text and selected date vertically . Not sure what I'm missing . Please help me out .

My stackBlitz link is [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datepicker1234?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.scss)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case when you need to style input with box angular-material provide that input 'appearance="outline"` if you want to use, like this

```
<mat-form-field appearance="outline">
    <mat-label>Outline form field</mat-label>
    <input matInput placeholder="Placeholder">
    <mat-icon matSuffix>sentiment_very_satisfied</mat-icon>
    <mat-hint>Hint</mat-hint>
  </mat-form-field>
```

Else if you want to style that custom like in your example then you need a some styling like give it `padding` when it has `float-label` like below

```
::ng-deep .mat-form-field.mat-form-field-should-float {
    padding-top:20px;
}
```

> REASON: Normal behavior of `mat-input` is that it float the label
>   above in some negative values, you can set that `float` to `never` so
>   that label doesn't go above, for more you can read in its [OFFICIAL
>   DOC]

(https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview)